# Passing parameters to GNU Parallel manually and by piping

Tags: linux, gnu-parallel

To set the stage, here is an example file structure:

```
test/1
test/2
test/3
```

I want to do this:

```
find -P -O3 "test/" -type f |
    parallel --use-cpus-instead-of-cores -j+0 --tmpdir "test/" --files ./test.bash
```

And pass another manual parameter to `test.bash` such that if it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

main() {
  echo "yay $1 $2!"
}

main "$1" "$2"
```

The output from `cat test/*.par` is:

```
yay test/1 param!
yay test/2 param!
yay test/3 param!
```

I've tried the following:

```
parallel --use-cpus-instead-of-cores -j+0 --tmpdir "test/" --files ./test.bash ::: 'param'
```

```
parallel --use-cpus-instead-of-cores -j+0 --tmpdir "test/" --files ./test.bash {} ::: 'param'
```

But they all fail and prioritize the manual parameter over the piped input.

Is there a way to perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit unsafe, because file names can contain delimiters (newlines):

```bash
find -P -O3 test/ -type f \
| parallel -j+0 --use-cpus-instead-of-cores \
           --tmpdir test/ \
           --files \
           -m ./test.bash {} 'param'
```

use instead:

```bash
find -P -O3 test/ -type f --print0 \
| parallel -0 \
           -j+0 --use-cpus-instead-of-cores \
           --tmpdir test/ \
           --files \
           -m ./test.bash {} 'param'
```

to make `find` separate results by the 0 byte (which can *not* appear in file names), and to make `parallel` use these.

However, why use `find` at all? Use `zsh`, instead of `bash`,

```bash
setopt extendedglob # usually already be on by default
setopt nullglob     # don't fail if no files found

parallel -j+0 --use-cpus-instead-of-cores \
         --tmpdir test/ \
         --files \
         -m ./test.bash {} 'param' \
   ::: test/**/*(.) 
###         ^^------- look recursively into all folders including the current
###                   (doesn't follow symlinks!)
###            ^----- for anything
###             ^^^-- as long as it's a file
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the [reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_examples.html#example-inserting-multiple-arguments)!

```bash
find -P -O3 test/ -type f \
| parallel -j+0 --use-cpus-instead-of-cores \
           --tmpdir test/ \
           --files \
           -m ./test.bash {} 'param'
```

Comment: You should actually follow the [advice from the reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_examples.html#example-working-as-xargs-n1-argument-appending) and use `find --print0` and `parallel -0`!